# Google Speech to Text Error: "Invalid recognition 'config': bad encoding.." for an MP3 file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I'm recording audio in a react web app using the "mic-recorder-to-mp3" node package.

I've used MediaInfo to look at the audio files produced using this library ([here's a sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eEMFaMGbYM2N-T04t81xTCF6TMdMecH1/view?usp=sharing)) and it shows the following information:
[image: Audio File Info]

So it doesn't appear to be corrupted or anything...however, when I run Google's Speech to Text API with the following code, I get the error: "Invalid recognition 'config': bad encoding.."

```
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

//configure the request:
const config = {
    enableWordTimeOffsets: true,
    sampleRateHertz: 48000,
    encoding: 'MP3',
    languageCode: 'en-US',
};
const audio = {
    content: fs.readFileSync(filename).toString('base64'),
};
const request = {
    config: config,
    audio: audio,
};

// Detects speech in the audio file
const [response] = await client.recognize(request);
```

I can't understand what's going wrong here...any help would be appreciated!

Comment: We have no access to the file posted, is it possible to make it public to make a test on my side?

Comment: Hi Enrique. My apologies, I just changed the permissions on the drive link so it should work just fine now. I've tried using a different microphone library which is working for me right now, but I think it would still be useful to me, and others, if we could figure this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue, seems that the encoding used is the root cause, I used the `gcloud ml speech recognize` command and I got no responses:

```
gcloud ml speech recognize gs://MY_BUCKET/audioClip.mp3 --language-code=en-US --encoding=linear16 --sample-rate=48000

{}
```

After that, I  changed the encoding of the file:

```
ffmpeg -i audioClip.mp3 audioClip.wav
```

Then I tried again and voilà:

```
gcloud ml speech recognize gs://MY_BUCKET/audioClip.wav --language-code=en-US --encoding=linear16 --sample-rate=48000

{
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.7809482,
          "transcript": "testing testing 1 2 3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Please consider that according to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding#audio-encodings) MP3 encoding is a Beta feature and only available in v1p1beta1. So, you should consider to  convert your file before to send it to the Speech to Text API.